# Symfony2 Render individual field

Tags: forms, templates, symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I'm having a problem rendering a custom individual field.

Adding the external template globally (config.yml) works but adding the same block in the same template doesn't.

form_elements.html.twig

```
{% block _user_email_widget %}
    <h1>test</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

template.html.twig (won't work)

```
{% form_theme form 'ProjectUserBundle:Form:form_elements.html.twig' %}
{% block content %}
{{form_widget(form.user)}}
{% endblock %}
```

config.yml (works)

```
twig:
    form:
        resources:
            - 'ProjectUserBundle:Form:form_elements.html.twig'
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed

The problem was on the template:

```
{% block content %}
    {% form_theme form 'ProjectUserBundle:Form:form_elements.html.twig' %}
    {{form_widget(form.user)}}
{% endblock %}
```

This is the right way to do that